# How can I modify a file while other threads read from it?

Tags: python

I'm multithreading data (both reading and writing) into/from a *single* text file.
I need to be able to replace or remove text from this file *without* replacing the actual file.

I cannot simply `.read()` into a string, then `.write()` a new file with the same name, because other threads are still using that file. I cannot `.write()` into a different file because threads need to `.read()` from this *single* file.

Is this possible?

Is there something equivalent to `file.replace()` or `file.remove()` or `file.delete()`?

Comment: Is there only one writing thread (and multiple reading threads)? Why does it have to be a file (as opposed to an in-memory object)? Couldn't you use a database where concurrent access is a lot easier?

Comment: I'm not so sure this will be thread-safe, but mmap seems like it may be relevant to your interests.  One issue is that if you .read(), you're getting string data that is no longer necessarily what's in the fire.

http://docs.python.org/release/3.2/library/mmap.html

Answer (score 2):

Bad idea. Use another thread which is sole responsible for writing/reading into the file. Or read the file into memory if it is not too big.

Answer (score 1):

Sure it's possible, but probably only useful if you were reading/writing into the file in a uniform way.  When I say uniform, you should treat the file as blocks of data.  Like say, every 4096 bytes is a block and you can do what you need on each block.  If you don't do this, then you would have to keep track of offsets on where the data and would make your program harder to manage.

After that, you can use the random access features for file I/O.  There's functions like `seek()` to move to a different offset in the file and `tell()` to tell the current offset.  You could then read or write from the current position.  Just think of it like you would memory because that's basically what it is.

I'm not sure what you're asking about the existence of `file.remove()`, `file.replace()`, `file.delete()` functions or how it would help you with what you are doing.  It defeats the purpose.

Also read more about the [Readers-writers problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers-writers_problem) to figure out how you can synchronize this.